# Remove parameters from url after redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is it possible to remove the parameters from a url after they have been used by using either php, JQuery or Javascript?

I would like to do this because I have jquery functions that are triggered by results of $_GET and at the moment if the user refreshes the page the functions are called again.

So that you can understand why I am doing is...

My site will only allow one person at a time to log in with each account and to prevent multiple simultaneous there is a db value changed when the account is being used.  Problem is I can't count on the user to log out without just closing the browser which means the value doesn't get changed and they can't get back in.  To get round this I have given the user the ability to close the other open session when they try to log in from another device.  At this point, when either the session on the other device has timed out or the other user clicks on a link, they are redirected to the home page with a message explaining why they have been logged out and the name of the person that did it.

The params in the redirect url triggers the message and has the name.

I have found lots of ways of removing params before the url is used but nothing about after which makes me ask the question is this possible?

Comment: Anything is possible. Let's start with what you have tried so far.

Comment: sure, but you'd need to do a client redirect to the new "clean" url.

Comment: sounds like you need a different approach for your jQuery functions, or track their usage

Comment: Turn on url rewriting and create a .htaccess file. Check for get parameters and just delete them from the url.

Comment: I think the fact that you need to do this is an indicator that you aren't using URL params for the right purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said before, you COULD go to the trouble of turning on url rewriting and create a .htaccess file that checks for the `GET` parameters and deletes them from the URL.

However, it may be better and easier to choose another option.

Such as setting `$_SESSION` variables prior to redirecting to the home page (with no `GET` parameters. Then you can just check for these session variables that indicate that the user is has been forcefully logged out and contain the message.